# Relative path of static files express/react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm running my react client on `localhost:3000` and my express server on `localhost:4000`, and I have a static folder in my server with images.

I'm trying to save the image path to a MySQL database, and use that in React as an img src, but can't figure out how to do it without hard coding the path. For example, `localhost:4000/images/img1.jpg` works, but if I change the host name tomorrow, all of my db data becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three answers:

1. In react you can fill props by joining a constant string and a variable. Just save the `/images/img1.jpg` in the database instead of full URL. Then in react do `<img src={'http://localhost:4000/' + imagePathFromDB} />`. When you change the server just change it once.
2. You can create a simple SQL query to update your DB to be relevant this is the beauty of SQL database.

For e.g.

```
update images set path=replace(path,'localhost:4000','newdomain.com')
```

Voilla!

3. If you using `create-react-app` you can serve the frontend and backend from the same domain using the [proxy parameter](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#docsNav). And then just save in the database `/myimage.jpg` and in React `<img src={myVariable} />`

Comment: Hi @nadav-lalo and welcome to SO. I hope this answer helped you. If not, leave a comment. If yes, you can upvote, and mark the answer as accepted.